# How to refresh view on click with knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to refresh view when clicking on it. I try something like this:

```
<tr data-bind="click: function(data, event) { 
    ko.cleanNode(event.currentTarget);
    ko.applyBindings(data, event.currentTarget); 
}">

    <!-- ko with: getProp("col1") -->
        <td data-bind="text: ko.computed(function() {...})"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->

</tr>
```

But this code does not work. I'm new to knockout.js and do not understand it in details.
Is there a way to fix this code?

Comment: Refreshing data manually is missing the point of using knockout. Try working through some tutorials at http://knockoutjs.com

Comment: Jason Spake, well, the project is not mine. I was just asked to make this code to work with minimum changes if it's possible.

Comment: @Zurab-D can you add if u see any error ? i'm trying to understand here, you are applying bindings to same element on click doesn't it make sense ? Not for me ! can you more code so to figure out whats best .

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshing the view"? What will refreshing a view accomplish? The ViewModel should be driving the View, if you wanted, you could add a click-function to the ViewModel which triggers the update of the View.